# Can't collectstatic to s3 via Heroku using boto - s3 bucket returns a NoneType

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto

this question pertains to a setup using Heroku, django-storages (w/ boto for s3), and CloudFront to serve static content.

I've been trying for the past several hours to successfully load up my static files to my Heroku app.  I have successfully got Cloudfront hooked to my s3 bucket, and it seems as though the bucket is set up properly, but for whatever reason, my value for `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` does not seem to registering properly.

If anyone has any clues or ideas on how to debug this, I'd be much obliged.  I am at my wit's end.  Thanks for reading.

settings.py (the important stuff):

```
try:
  from settings_local import *
except:
  import s3utils
DEBUG = False
#s3 stuff
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'  
STATIC_URL = 'https://[domain].cloudfront.net/'
#use heroku postgres database
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

s3utils.py

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
import os

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'static.[website].org'

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

This is the traceback I get when attempting to collectstatic, either via 'heroku run' or in the Procfile:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 113, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 287, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 215, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 284, in exists
    return k.exists()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 399, in exists
    return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 148, in lookup
    return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 181, in get_key
    query_args=query_args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 458, in make_request
    auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 92, in build_auth_path
    path = '/' + bucket
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Note that I've omitted domain names and such, I don't actually have [domain] or [website] in the code.

Comment: I don't want to say that I am answering this question because it really isn't a satisfactory answer as to why THIS problem is occurring, but putting:

    `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'static.[website].org'`

in settings.py before my try/except block seems to work.  Can anyone with a better understanding of Python explain why this would be the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not saying `from s3utils import *`, so `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` is never imported into the settings module.

`S3BotoStorage` will pull `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` from environment variables, but `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` must be set in `settings.py`. This seems like a bizarre inconsistency, but I think it is because `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are actually `boto` parameters and `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` is not (`boto` will pull credentials from env vars).*

The other references to s3utils are explicit:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
```

So, the only setting that isn't taken care of is `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, and that causes your error.

*I'd like to see django-storages accept other settings from env vars ([12-Factor App, anyone?](http://www.12factor.net/config)) and am considering opening an issue/submitting a pull request to that effect.

Comment: Sorry I never accepted this, but that is exactly what the issue was.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for help, I had all setup but wrong variable name for "AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", thanks a lot.