# s3 bucket returns NoneType

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Exact same issue as here:
[Can't collectstatic to s3 via Heroku using boto - s3 bucket returns a NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228386/cant-collectstatic-to-s3-via-heroku-using-boto-s3-bucket-returns-a-nonetype?rq=1)

This still does not fix the issue.

Important part of my settings.py

```
from base64 import b64decode
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False       # use http instead of https
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False     # don't add complex authentication-related query parameters for requests
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <snip>     # enter your access key id
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = <snip> # enter your secret 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket/images/'
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

Upon runserver, collectstatic or executing from celery. I get the same error:

```
File "/virtualenv/path/to/site-package/boto/s3/connection.py", line 94, in build_auth_path
path = '/' + bucket
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Environment variables are set for keyid, access key and bucket name. Interestingly changing

```
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

to

```
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Results in an even stranger error:

```
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
ImportError: cannot import name signals
```

The website was otherwise working fine before I started trying this s3 integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your settings.py:

`from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage`

It's not needed for anything, and it's causing this error. When you import `S3BotoStorage`, that class tries to get the bucket name and other settings from settings.py. To avoid an infinite import loop, Python will only let the S3BotoStorage class import variables from settings.py that were set before the `import S3BotoStorage` line. All other variables will show up as `None`, which includes that important `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` setting.

As a side note, your bucket name setting (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME) should not contain a '`/`', which is not allowed in a bucket name. That may cause other errors for you  after this one is fixed. You can include the full path in your `S3_URL` setting, though.