# Not null gcs bucket returned "can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, boto3, boto

I am very new to google clould storage. I am using tutorial https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin to create a bucket to google cloud storage using boto. Please find code below:

```py
    import boto
    import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
    import time

    GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
    LOCAL_FILE = 'file'

    CLIENT_ID = "hnsdndsjsksoasjmoadsj"
    CLIENT_SECRET = "jdijeroerierper-er0erjfdkdf"

    gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.SetFallbackClientIdAndSecret(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

    now = time.time()

    # Your project ID can be found at https://console.cloud.google.com/
    # If there is no domain for your project, then project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT'
    project_id = 'my-project-4749485'


    now = time.time()
    CATS_BUCKET = 'cats-%d' % now
    DOGS_BUCKET = 'dogs-%d' % now

    for name in (CATS_BUCKET, DOGS_BUCKET):
      uri = boto.storage_uri(name, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
      try:
        header_values = {"x-goog-project-id": project_id}
        uri.create_bucket(headers=header_values)

        print('Successfully created bucket "%s"' % name)
      except boto.exception.StorageCreateError as e:
        print('Failed to create bucket:', e)
```

When I run it I get:

```
/Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/venv/bin/python /Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/elrond/deploy3.py -t test -v 0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/elrond/deploy3.py", line 28, in <module>
    uri.create_bucket(headers=header_values)
  File "/Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto/storage_uri.py", line 574, in create_bucket
    storage_class)
  File "/Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 95, in create_bucket
    data=get_utf8_value(data))
  File "/Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 659, in make_request
    auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
  File "/Users/dilipyadav/githome/elrond/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 94, in build_auth_path
    path = '/' + bucket
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I found similar issue here - [Can't collectstatic to s3 via Heroku using boto - s3 bucket returns a NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228386/cant-collectstatic-to-s3-via-heroku-using-boto-s3-bucket-returns-a-nonetype/15936697#15936697), but it did not help.

Note: CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and project_id are replaced with random characters.

Edit:

```py
    def build_auth_path(self, bucket, key=''):
        key = boto.utils.get_utf8_value(key)
        path = ''
        if bucket != '':
            path = '/' + bucket
        return path + '/%s' % urllib.parse.quote(key)
```

The above is a code snippet from connection.py where my code fails. On debugging I get bucket name as "cats-1567682436" which is a byte value. I guess it's failing when the path is created with string '/' and byte bucket. So concatenation fails.

Comment: Yea You got good assumptions, so just execute on the `bucket` the `decode` method with desired encoding for example `UTF-8`.

Comment: We cannot make a change to connection.py as it is a gs library.

Comment: I think you may have to force the name of the buckets to be encoded in utf-8 as they seem to be created in bytes type insted of string. Can you try adding `.decode("utf-8") `, so this line looks like: `uri = boto.storage_uri(name.decode("utf-8"), GOOGLE_STORAGE)`?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
path = '/' + bucket
```

To this:

```
path = '/' + bucket.decode('utf-8')
```

However, I would change the code that calls `build_auth_path()` and convert the bucket `bytearray` to a `string` first and then call `build_auth_path()`.

Answer (score 0):

In `boto/utils.py:871`
Patch the line to

```py
value = str(value.encode('utf-8'))
```

It's a bug of the `get_utf8_value()` function which turns a string into a byte array. The library is old and won't likely fix this.

Answer (score 0):

when I encountered an error, it was solved by the following way:

0. `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 venv/`
1. `source venv/bin/activate`
2. `git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git -b develop`
3. In boto/utils.py:871 Patch the line to `value = str(value.encode('utf-8'))`
4. from boto/ `python setup.py install`
5. `git clone https://github.com/henrysher/duplicity`
6. `cd duplicity` && `python setup.py install`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who (like me) arrived here after having issues integrating GCS with duplicity, encoding as above caused issues further down the line, and the solution is simply to append the `--s3-use-new-style` flag to your duplicity command.